# OnMouseOver() and OnMouseExit()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a number of planes to use as my terrain and give them `OnMouseOver()` to change them to some color and `OnMouseExit()` to change them back to the original color.

I attached a plane instantiation script to the main camera to generate the plane prefab and a mouse event script to the plane `prefab`. I get them all instantiated and the events pass to them, but in-game the mouse events are being applied to either long strips of planes, an entire quadrant, or a random single plane not at the location of the mouse cursor.

I made a new material and applied it to the place prior to turning it into a prefab to replace the standard material set upon creation of the plane.

I have started attempting to use the mouse position to apply the color change to the plane at the current mouse position with `Physics.CheckSphere`, but I don't fully understand how to tell specifically what `gameObject` is at a specific position.

```
public class TerrainGeneration : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform groundTile;
    private Vector3 row;
    private int max = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        for ( int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= max; x++) {

                row = new Vector3(i, 0, x);
                Instantiate(groundTile, row, Quaternion.identity);

            }    
        }
    }
}


public class MouseEvents : MonoBehaviour {

    private Color isTargeted;
    private Color notTargeted;
    private MeshRenderer groundTileMeshRenderer;
    private Vector3 mousePosition;
    private float mouseX;
    private float mouseY;

    void Start () {

        groundTileMeshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        isTargeted = Color.cyan;
        notTargeted = groundTileMeshRenderer.material.color;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        mouseX = Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        mouseY = Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        mousePosition = new Vector3(mouseX, 0, mouseY);

        if (Physics.CheckSphere(mousePosition, 1))
        {
            **//Get the specific gameObject located at the current mouse position
            //Set the gameObject as the target for the color change**
        }
    }

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        groundTileMeshRenderer.material.color = isTargeted;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        groundTileMeshRenderer.material.color = notTargeted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out what the answer is thanks to the Unity forums. My error was in the instantiation transform script. Because I was using the plane primitive 3d object I was not accounting for the size of the plane correctly. The following code snippet for instantiation of each row removes the overlapping that was occurring as the planes are too large to simply place at `(0,0,0)`, `(0,0,1)`, `(0,0,2)` for example.

```
row = new Vector3(i * 10, 0, x * 10);
Instantiate(groundTile, row, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: This is great news, glad you found it. Mark your Answer as accepted so that others can use this Q&A in the future for value.

Answer (score 0):

`tag` your gameObjects as necessary and then you can identify them.

[image]

If you do, then you can use them like so (purely for example):

```
public virtual void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "planeA")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand this idea. I applied the tag to the prefab.
This is the code that I tried and nothing happened. 

public virtual void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GroundTile")
        {
            groundTileMeshRenderer.material.color = isTargeted;
        } else
        {
            groundTileMeshRenderer.material.color = notTargeted;
        }
    }

Regardless of the answer to my problem I am also still very curious as to why OnMouseOver() affects large chunks of gameObjects even if the mouse isn't touching them.

Comment: I think it’s because there actually isn’t a “collision” occurring. My example was just how to use a tag. I’ll do some research and come back to this.

Comment: Take a look here in the meantime, I've got to leave: https://answers.unity.com/questions/547513/how-do-i-detect-when-mouse-passes-over-an-object.html